Возможно ли сохранить обученную модель "Object Detection with TensorFlow Lite Model Maker" в одном файле как model.keras zip archive?
Руководствуясь https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker/object_detection#change_the_model_architecture
создал, обучил и на валидационном датасете убедился, что обученная модель с приемлемой точностью детектирует объекты.
Опущу установку зависимостей и создание датасетов, рабочий код по созданию и обучению модели выглядит следующим образом:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os from tflite_model_maker.config
import ExportFormat, QuantizationConfig from tflite_model_maker
import model_spec from tflite_model_maker
import object_detector from tflite_support import metadata
    
# Load model spec
spec = object_detector.EfficientDetSpec(model_name='efficientdet-lite2', uri='https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/lite2/feature-vector/1', model_dir='/content/checkpoints', hparams={'max_instances_per_image': 8000})
    
# Train the model
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=4, train_whole_model=True, epochs=20, validation_data=val_data)
    
# Evaluate the model
eval_result = model.evaluate(val_data)
    
# Print COCO metrics
print("COCO metrics:") for label, metric_value in eval_result.items():
        print(f"{label}: {metric_value}")

COCO метрики показывают, что с обученной моделью все хорошо.
В примере документации tensorflow.org, далее модель экспортируется и сохраняется в формате *.tflite
Вопрос - есть ли путь, чтобы эту, уже обученную модель, сохранить как "Save the entire model" (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) ?
При попытке выполнить в следующей строке:
model.save('trained_detector_model.h5', save_format='h5')

приводит к:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/train.py", line 66, in <module>
    model.save('trained_detector_model.h5', save_format='h5')
AttributeError: 'ObjectDetector' object has no attribute 'save'

